# iOS Simulator 6.x does not start on xCode5 installed side-by-side with xCode6 on 10.9+

Tags: xcode, xcode5, ios-simulator

I finally upgraded to Yosemite but also had this issue on Mavericks.

I downloaded xCode5.1.1 and installed moving to Applications folder and selecting "Keep both", so it renamed the Xcode.app folder to Xcode 2.app. I renamed it to Xcode5.app then.

Now starting the xCode5 and installing all the 6.x SDKs iam unable to start the simulator. It stays black screen.

When i run the iPhone Simulaotr manually from console i get lots of "Service cannot load in requested session" messages.

It tried to load *.plist files from within the /Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/tmp/LaunchDeamons/com.apple.....plist, but that tmp folder is empty.

In xCode5.1.1 on preferences -> Locations i set the command line tools to xCode5.1.1.

But still i cannot load the ios6.x simulator, it works for 7+, but 6 does not load at all. Its just a black screen.

Answer (score 0):

Simulators older than 7.1 will not run correctly on OS X Yosemite.  If you need iOS 6.1 and 7.0 simulators, you need to install Mavericks.

Similarly, if you need the iOS 5.1 and 6.0 simulators, you need Mountain Lion.